# Loading csv to mysql-python3

Tags: mysql, csv, python-3.4, pymysql

I can import csv to mysql using Sequel pro with no problem. Need to do it in my python program. Couldn't find the answer online. Looks like mysqldb is not a good match for python ver 3. Using Mypysql can't find any note in documentation if it has this functionality.

OS: Mac

Comment: Is `load data infile` mysql command unavailable?

Comment: thank you, I am new to sql/python.

Comment: @Shadow it worked.